# Programmatically converting SLDPRT to STL file without external tools, APIs, etc

Tags: python, binary, hex, file-conversion, cad

I am working on attempting to convert SLDPRT (as well as STEP) files to STL files programmatically without the use of external tools or APIs.

Here's an example of an API that does this: https://anyconv.com/sldprt-to-stl-converter/

I understand that STL files are binary files that can simply be converted to ASCII. I am trying to figure out what text encoding is used on SLDPRT files and how I can extract this into readable text that can be parsed and formatted as an STL file. I currently have a web page created with JavaScript and PHP in which I would like to upload SLDPRT files, convert them to STL files on the server, and view them in THREE.js.

**Using Python Code**

```
filename = "LABL_Double.SLDPRT"

with open(filename, "rb") as file:
    hex_list = [ord(c) for c in f'{file.read()}']
    print(hex_list)`
```

I used the following code to attempt to look inside the SolidWorks file and received a long list of integers such as:

```
[123, 23, 34, 5, 23, 0, ... 57, 97, 112, 91, 39]
```

If I change the code to the following:

```
filename = "LABL_Double.SLDPRT"

with open(filename, "rb") as file:
    print(file.read())
```

I then receive a binary string output with hex values as such:

```
b'\x87>\xd1#\x00\x00\x00\x04k...\xd2\x1d\xafxa8\xbe\xc4\x8c\x9ap['
```

What can I do with these two different outputs from reading the SLDPRT file. Can either of them be converted to human-readable text that can be parsed and converted into an STL file? I know this is possible to do stand alone within a program because tools like SolidWorks and the provided API above are capable of this. Any help regarding knowledge behind what is going inside SolidWorks files would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK SLDPRT is a proprietary file format. Unless you hand on some specifications which tells you how to decode the file's content you will stay stuck at this gibberish-like level.

Comment: Is it possible then to determine some kind of decoding algorithm for this file or is it likely exclusive to SolidWorks?

Comment: SolidWorks may provide some documents and/or API for decoding those files. However, this might be subject to some kind of licensing. Take a tour at SolidWorks web site, they provide a Python API